# How do I stop Firefox from going to a previous page when I swipe my trackpad right?

Tags: firefox

Firefox is set with the same feature that Chrome comes with where you can swipe left or right and it will change pages. It's a pretty annoying feature and I tend to accidentally switch pages. I looked around on super user and wasn't able to find an answer.

How do I disable that feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to `about:config` in the address line:
   [image]
2. In the search box, type `browser.gesture.swipe`:
   [image]
3. Click on the edit button (pencil icon) of either `browser.gesture.swipe.left` or `browser.gesture.swipe.right`:
   [image]
4. Delete the value and click save (checkmark icon):
   [image]

Comment: Funny story. I did that and it disabled the forward and back buttons on my mouse, so...

Comment: That appears to have been related to Logitech options having horizontal scroll set to "Change Pages". Changing it to Horizontal scroll fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Yea, as BrainStorm.exe wrote, it has something to do with Logitech options. Once I've installed it my scrolling in firefox did not work. I had to change my settings in logitech from back/forward to CMD + left arrow / CMD + right arrow

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).